# MatchCollection throws Evaluation timed out error

Tags: c#, regex, runtime-error

I am using this regular expression for finding `methods`.
So please give a optimized regex pattern for the finding `methods`.

I have debugged the project and it's throwing error for `System.EventArgs eventArgs` and 
`System.Windows.Forms.HelpEventArgs hlpEvent`

```
var pattern = @"\b(public|private|internal|protected)\s*" +
              @"\b(static|virtual|abstract)?\s*[a-zA-Z_]*(?<method>\s[a-zA-Z_]+\s*)" + 
              @"\((([a-zA-Z_\[\]\<\>]*\s*[a-zA-Z_]*\s*)[,]?\s*)+\)";
```

> Error: Evaluating the function 'function' timed out and needed to be aborted in an unsafe way

Comment: This is catastrophic backtracking. To fix it, we'd need to know the rules your pattern must follow. The problem is mostly with `@"\((([a-zA-Z_\[\]\<\>]*\s*[a-zA-Z_]*\s*)[,]?\s*)+\)"` part as there are 6 optional `*`- or `?`-quantified patterns in a `+`-quantified group followed with an obligatory `\)` pattern. `\s*` throughout the pattern are also a trouble.

Comment: Best to give test code on [regex101](https://regex101.com/).

Comment: Instead of trying to implement a compiler with regex, may I suggest using the Roslyn compiler platform instead? See examples: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Getting-Started-C%23-Syntax-Analysis

Comment: @OliverHao In this case, a .NET regex compatible online tester will be more appropriate, like regexhero.net or regexstorm.net.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you please provide the regular expression to match functions which wont throw error

Comment: Use Roslyn, not regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can please give any link for that Roslyn resource

Comment: @Misza can u please elobrate on that how to implement